# how can i force any input to keep over Keypad when Keypad opened using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i'm working in a .NET project "for mobile" using Jquery Mobile and html.
The problem is happening only on Samsung Galaxy device,
when i click on input the keypad comes over the input and the input got hidden behind the keypad till i start to type any thing ,so how can i solve this problem? i want to make the keypad push the input to above not to hide the input.

Comment: Try to provide a testcase on http://jsfiddle.net so people can reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: @Nelson, is there some way of getting a soft-keyboard to appear on JSFiddle then? If there is I'd like to know about it :)

Comment: @DaveR Yes, it's rather easy, you just put a normal input, and when I navigate your jsfiddle with my android phone and touch the input the soft-keyboard will appear, at that point I can see if it's displaying it right or not, and do changes to the fiddle to try to fix it..

Comment: @Nelson it doesn't make sense to provide my case in Jsfiddle as this issue happened only on Samsung Galaxy tab as i mentioned.